# IOS/Autolayout: How to fix width of large textview?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am having a horrible time trying to fix the width of a textview in autolayout.  The textview is the dominant element in the screen so my inability to fix it is wrecking the entire screen.

The set up is a view containing a scrollview, containing a content view containing elements.  Following Apple's instructions, I set the width of the view, scrollview and content view to 375 and pinned the contentview to the scrollview and scrollview to the view on all four sides, all with constants of 0.

I would like the textview to be centered and fairly wide.  Accordingly, I first set it with a leading constant to contentview of 40, a trailing constant to contentview of 40, and a width of 295.  On a 7 Plus, this left too wide a margin at the right and on a SE, the textview extended beyond the right margin. The natural thing seemed to be to remove the width constraint so there was only a leading and trailing constraint but this caused the entire view to shrink town to 113.  There is no discernible reason I can come up with for this to happen, but happen it did.  I then tried resetting to 295 but less than or equal.  I also tried setting to 295 but lowering the priority.  At priority 750, it acted as though at 1000.  At priority 500, the view shrank back down to 113.

[image]
[image]

Most exasperating.  Attached see screenshots of the constraints.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit:

It appears from [this post](https://medium.com/@pj_/ios-tips-dynamic-uitextview-102e73853fbc) that UITextViews may not adjust their size in response to autolayout. So perhaps there is no way to do this all in autolayout instoryboard with wiring a constraint and modifying it with code.  I can't believe that Apple does not support autolayout with textviews in story board so still hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control drag from the content view to the outmost view and make them **Equal Widths**

Comment: That makes sense. However, I deleted the centerx constraint and width constraint for noteView and the entire scene immediately shrunk in width to about half the size of the view.  The contentVIew shrunk from 375 to 143.5 and the notesview shrunk from 295 to to 63.5.  This actually makes a wierd sort of sense.  If the leading and trailing are each 40, then the notesview should be 80 less than the contentview.  But I can't understand why both the contentview and notesview shrink by 231.5 when I remove the width for the notesview.

Comment: I also tried deleting the leading and trailing constraints and then "re-pinning" the notesview on the left and right to the contentview with constants of 40.  However, it does not help.  The contentview immediately resized its width to 143.5.

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the notesview is pinned to the contentview but the contentview is taking its width from the notesview which does not have an assigned width.  It is ending up with the bizarre width of 63.5 for the notesview which may be an artificact of some other horizontal offsets with other elements that are supposed to be based on the noteview width derived from the contentview, not the other way around

Comment: Remove 375 width of the contentView and set it to the viewController's  view

Comment: ContentView is not set to 375.  It is pinned on all four sides to the scrollview and the scrollview is pinned on all four sides to the outer ViewController as per the constraints shown above.  However, the contentview does not seem to be getting its size from being pinned to the Scrollview and View Controller which is what I want.  It is getting its size from the notesView.  In the absence of a horizontal size to the notesview, this is shrinking to 63 which is the sum of two small labels pinned to the notesview.

Comment: Control drag from the content view to the outmost view and make them equal widths

Comment: Do you want to edit your answer to specify add "Equal Widths" constraint and I will mark it as correct?  That is what worked.

Comment: Thanks.  That literally took me two days.  Setting them to equal widths forces the content view to take its width from the VC rather than from the subviews.

Comment: When you use scrollView as apple recommends to first put a contentView inside it and then add elements to it , keep in mind that scrollView is like gelly needs to get it's content(width, height) from the contView that should take it's width from any outer view and it's height from pinning all elements correctly from top to bottom that how scrollview knows its content to show without shrinking or any other un-expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are setting the width of your view/scrollView/contentView to a fixed width, i.e. 375 pt. This would obviously give you problems on smaller screens (like iPhone 5) and larger ones (like Plus).

You should in stead set the content view to have equal width as your outermost view.

If you are working with a storyboard and your outermost view is the main view of a view-controller then its width is already set for you are good to go.
If in stead you have a xib then the width of the view should be set where you are adding it as a subview. Obviously its width should be set relative to the screen width.

Comment: I am pinning the widths of the scrollview and contentview to the outermost view controller.  Nowhere do I manually set them.  For the outermost VC, it has to have some width so I set it to 375 not with a constraint but in the size inspector.  I believe storyboard now sets them by default to 600.  I don't know of any way for them not to have some width.